# Fixing Bad badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email in Git Repository

Tags: git, github

I have a git repository I am attempting to move to github from bitbucket. This is something I have done before without much difficulty, both using the github importer tool and manually sending up a repo. In this particular case, however, my repository seems to have an issue in its history, which causes github to fail. Notably, when I run git fsck, I get:

```
git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error in commit 18e86b4bdd4172bfca9f635abfedc84a8bf39bd7: badEmail: invalid author/committer line - bad email
Checking objects: 100% (90779/90779), done.
```

Git fsck seems to be telling there is a single bad commit, but when I [look at this commit](https://bitbucket.org/stefika/quorum-language/commits/18e86b4bdd4172bfca9f635abfedc84a8bf39bd7), I do not see an obvious reason why it is incorrect (e.g., perhaps a rogue hidden character in the email?). In any case, in order to fix this, the first thing I have tried is to rebase. The tutorial I have [attempted to follow](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html) seems to suggest to grab the parent commit, rebase, then switch to edit instead of pick in the list. When I do that I am getting a merge conflict:

```
Auto-merging HourOfCode/SourceCode/Biology.quorum
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in HourOfCode/SourceCode/Biology.quorum
error: could not apply 18e86b4bd... Updated Breed method, IsParent method, added Tasks 2 - 6 sample code.
```

If I try to run the next commands in the tutorial anyway (typical amend commands), I get this:

```
git commit --amend --author="My Name <nyname@name.com>"
U   HourOfCode/SourceCode/Biology.quorum
error: Committing is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
```

Now, I know I could just add the file, but given the impact rebase can have on a repo, it is not clear I have any of this right. I know if such a change goes through everyone will have to re-clone, but my question is, how do I fix this "bad email" into something acceptable and push up this history changing change without damaging my public repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the actual commit in question (raw content), and the problem:

```
$ git cat-file -p 18e86b4bdd4172bfca9f635abfedc84a8bf39bd7
tree 3c1ca25101ec266daa5b7cc8f71b9cbcb5365b73
parent 03f8e6b99fbd996fffe03bda5aeeb17c325893b3
author timkwist <timkwist@hotmail.com> 1402964633 -0700
committer timkwist <timkwist@hotmail.com <> 1402964633 -0700

Updated Breed method, IsParent method, added Tasks 2 - 6 sample code.$
```

The `committer` line should not have the extra `<>` after the (presumably correct) email address, before the two numeric values.  (The commit message also does not end with a newline, as you can see by the prompt showing up on the same line, but that's not something `git fsck` will object to.)

> ... In any case, in order to fix this, the first thing I have tried is to rebase.

Do not use rebase here!  (You could *theoretically* use `git rebase --rebase-merges` but that's still the wrong way to go.)

To replace a bad commit like this, use `git replace --edit` followed by either `git filter-branch` (obsolete now) or `git filter-repo` (the new better way, but still not part of Git distributions).  But:

> ... but given the impact rebase can have on a repo, it is not clear I have any of this right. I know if such a change goes through everyone will have to re-clone

That's true however you go about making this change.  The reason is that the hash ID of a commit *is* the commit; making any change to any part, including removing the bogus `<>` on the `committer` line, results in a *new and different commit* with a new and different unique hash ID.  All subsequent commits in the repository must refer back to the new commit, directly (for its children) or indirectly (for its grand<sup>n</sup>children, n ≥ 1).

Your best bet, if other constraints allow it, is simply to *ignore the problem*.  Git itself doesn't have any issues reading and using this commit and its files.  It just fails to meet the *formal requirements* (so some other non-Git software that reads Git data might object to it, since accepting it is an extension).  That's why `git fsck` gripes about it.  You can disable this particular error message for an entire clone:

```
git config fsck.badEmail ignore
```

or for certain known bad commits by hash ID.  Whether (and how) you can get GitHub or Bitbucket to do this for you, I'm not sure.  See, e.g., https://github.blog/2015-09-29-git-2-6-including-flexible-fsck-and-improved-status/ (which mentions the `fsck.badEmail` setting, and also the skip-list trick, but not a way to set that up *on GitHub itself*, and of course you're trying to do this on Bitbucket).

Of course, I was able to clone the entire repository *from* Bitbucket just now to find this out, so it seems that it's safely there.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you. I definitely can confirm what you are saying is true and adjusting fsck does let me ignore it locally. But, I still can't for the life of me get it to github because their fsck setting doesn't ignore it.

Comment: Do you have a sense of "how" to use graft for this commit? I'm still not sure I follow this piece.

Comment: You'd use `git replace --edit <commit-hash>` to construct the replacement commit to graft into place. I'll fix the answer (should say `git replace`, not `git graft`, that's a reference to the ancient `.git/grafts` hack that should not be used).

Comment: This solved my problem and thank you. I cannot express how much this reduced my frustration at this problem.